# Normalised versus true racing times as DV for a learning experiment?

Tags: regression, ancova, measurement, dependent-variable

I have a question about using ratios as variables in alpine ski racing research. We want to compare skiers' performance on different days, but snow conditions affect the results. To address this, we normalized performance when skiers ski straight down without turns. However, this normalization centers scores around 0.5 seconds, even if skiers have very different raw times. For example, good skiers tend to be heavier, making their straight gliding times hard to beat, and bad skiers, who are lighter, seem better than they are. I'm unsure where to argue against using this normalization in research where I'm interested in estimating group differences between experimental groups using POST ~ PRE + GROUP + ERROR.is it best to focus on raw racing time performance or the normalised DV in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalizing seems like a mistake to me. If you want to adjust for snow conditions, then add those conditions as a variable (or maybe more than one variable).  And if, as I suspect, you have multiple times for each skier, then consider a multi-level model.

If there is no good way to operatinalize conditions, you could use day and time, which would be a marker for conditions.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Do you think based on the observation I described (i.e that skiers have a harder task to beat their straight gliding times), or do you have something to add? Yes, I will use a multilevel model. I have 20-30 skiers nested within 4 groups of skiers. Some groups are elite (olympians) and other elite and skilled. Total of 99 skiers. I have multiple run per skiers for each day. The experiment was conducted in an indoor skiing hall in Norway. Thanks

Comment: Normalizing seems to turn this into a question that makes very little sense.